# USB Unrecognized. Different

Tags: usb, keyboard, desktop-computer

I have this very weird issue with my PC.

I have an electric outlet with two slots.

1 for my PC AVR
1 for my Extension wire. for my routers, etc.

Whenever I plug a device in my Extension wire. My PC keyboard, mouse and etc as long as it is USB. Suddenly becomes unrecognized. then will function again after a few seconds.

Do you have any diagnosis for this?

Answer (score 0):

If they are becoming unrecognized, it is likely that a new check is being triggered whenever you plug in something to your extension wire.

There's a voltage drop whenever you plug something into your extension, but your AVR should be managing it. My advice is to check if your AVR is working correctly.